# Copying string from one structure to another structure

Tags: c, arrays, string, structure

I am trying to write a program that alphabetically sorts a small dictionary. To do this, I need to be able to copy strings from the unsorted dictionary to the sorted dictionary. If I try to copy an entire string as such:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct entry
{
    char word[15];
    char definition[50];
};


void dictionarySort(struct entry dictionary[]) {
    int i;

    struct entry dictionary2[100] = {{}};

    for (i = 0; i <= strlen(&dictionary->word[0]); i++) {
        dictionary2[0].word[i] = dictionary[0].word[i];

    }
    dictionary2[0].word = dictionary[0].word;

    printf("%s\n",dictionary2[0].word);

}

int main (void) {
    struct entry dictionary[100] = 
    {{"aerie", "a high nest"},
    {"abyss", "a bottomless pit"},
    {"ahoy", "a nautical call of greeting"},
    {"addle", "to become confused"},
    {"aardvark", "a burrowing African mammal"},
    {"agar", "a jelly made of seaweed"},
    {"acumen", "mentally sharp; keen"},
    {"aigrette", "an ornamental cluster of feathers"},
    {"affix", "to attach"},
    {"ajar", "partially opened"}};
    dictionarySort(dictionary);
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
error: array type 'char [15]' is not assignable
        dictionary2[0].word = dictionary[0].word;
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
```

On the other hand, if I copy individual characters, I have no way of differentiating the strings, which is necessary when dictionary2 is accessed.

Answer (score 2):

As your compiler tells you arrays are not assignable in c, to copy a string you need the `strcpy()` function

```
strcpy(dictionary2[0].word[i], dictionary[0].word[i]);
```

you need to ensure that the destination array has enough space to hold the string, that is the number of characters in the string `+1` for the `nul` terminator.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into using `qsort` (if you have a linux/mac type `man qsort` for more info)

the qsort call will look like `qsort(dictionary,size_of_arr, sizeof(entry), func_name);` You will have to make a comparison function named `func_name` (though you can call it whatever you want, as long as you pass it properly in the function call.

```
int func_name(void *ent1, void *ent2)
{
    struct entry a = *(struct entry*)ent1, b = *(struct entry*)ent2;
    return strcmp(a.word, b.word);
}
```

I think that'll work, if not something close to it will...

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a function to assign strings ( character arrays as well )

common function to do this is :

```
char a[15];
strcpy( a , "ameer" ); % copying second string to first one
```

from  library that means a="ameer";

so in your case you can write :

```
strcpy( dictionary2[0].word , dictionary[0].word );
```

Answer (score 0):

`dictionary2[0].word[i] = dictionary[0].word[i];` is plain wrong. You cannot copy one array into another as assignment operation as you do for say `int` type.

You can use strcpy(or strncpy) to copy the bytes from one array into another. Or use memcpy.

```
strcpy(dictionary2[0].word[i], dictionary[0].word[i]); 



memcpy(dictionary2[0].word[i],
dictionary[0].word[i],sizeof(dictionary[0].word));
```

Answer (score -1):

What you are trying to do is copy 1 string completely with an assignment operator '='. You can either do it in a for loop or use strcpy().